# redefine a default parameter for a imported function

Tags: python, svg

I am using a code that (among other things) generate a svg file of the geometry that I create.

Given an input script my-geometry.py, the structure of the code is the following:

```
python pre.py my-geometry
```

In pre.py t is called another module:

```
from render import *
[...] some other code
execfile(script, globals()) #script=my-geometry
```

render.py itself import another module

```
from svg_render import *
[...]
svg = SvgEnvironment(x,y,title='a',desc='b')
svg.text(x_mid, y_mid, blk.label, anchor="middle")
[...]
```

where `SvgEnvironment` is a class defined in `svg_render`. The `text` method of the class is defined as:

```
def text(self, x, y, textString, angle=0.0, fontSize=10,
         anchor="start", colour="black",
         fontFamily="sanserif")
```

My question is: how is it possible to modify/override the default value of `fontSize`,from `my-geometry.py`? (What i want to do, is to modify the fontsize for all text that it is written to the svg without modyfing the source code)

I had a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625695/is-it-possible-to-change-a-functions-default-parameters-in-python)  , but it seems not to fit to my case.

Comment: You can use monkeypatch, replace existing function with your new code. If you want to do with monkeypatch, then I can give solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Monkey Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patch) or override function.

**Monkey Patch**

```
#File: render.py

from svg_render import SvgEnvironment

def modified_text(self, x, y, textString, angle=0.0, fontSize=<change size>,
         anchor="start", colour="black",
         fontFamily="sanserif")


SvgEnvironment.text = modified_text
```

This will replace whole function and when ever it used it will get new default value.

**Override**

```
#File: render.py

from svg_render import SvgEnvironment

class MySvgEnvironment(SvgEnvironment):
    def text(self, x, y, textString, angle=0.0, fontSize=<change size>,
         anchor="start", colour="black",
         fontFamily="sanserif")



...
...
svg = MySvgEnvironment(x,y,title='a',desc='b')
svg.text(x_mid, y_mid, blk.label, anchor="middle")
...
...
```

Comment: Your answer implies to modify the file render.py, that' s not what I want, because I want to override the function at the script level (my-geometry.py) (at least, if it is possible)