# Python Logging exc_info By Default

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am looking for a way to have `logging.info`, `logging.warning`, `logging.error`, etc. set `exc_info=True` by default. Refactoring the project to include this parameter isn't feasible at this point, so I'm looking for a way to set this for the `logging` module at a project-wide scope.

I am specifically looking for a way to set this parameter. Workarounds to retrieve the exception like `sys.exc_info` or `traceback.format_exc()` are not what I'm looking for.

Additionally, please let me know if this just isn't possible.

Comment: It's possible, but doesn't sound useful at all.  The exc info will be `NoneType` and `None` unless you're logging from within an except block.  Why on earth would you want that true / on by default?

Comment: Because of project requirements outside of my control... Is this possible from a config or do I have to overload the functions themselves? I've been reading through the logging documentation and haven't found a relevant config.

Comment: There is a requirement outside of your control for log files to be littered with useless `NoneType: None` everywhere?

Comment: Yes; is there something in ```logging.Config``` that can achieve this behavior or should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: @wim seems like you want to be helpful, and understand, thus you ask for an example use case => Personnaly, I use sentry to log error, but when using python's logging to explicitely throw an error, the stacktrace is not available by default in sentry; I need to set exc_info=True. Makes sense ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer in case anyone has a similar problem - taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625695/is-it-possible-to-change-a-functions-default-parameters-in-python).

The easiest way I've found is to use `functools.partial` at the start of your project. This allows you to change the default parameter value, while still being able to set it to `False` for specific function calls if you want to!

```
import logging
from functools import *

logging.info = partial(logging.info, exc_info=True)
```

Comment: This will only affect the root logger.

Comment: In this case that's the behavior I desire; thank you for explicitly pointing this out in case it would be a problem for anyone else!