# Set sep-parameter for print-function globally

Tags: python, printing, printf, global

Is there a way to globally set the `sep` parameter of the `print` function?
I'm getting tired of always doing this manually for every `print` statement.

Simple example:

```
some_superlong_list : List # existing list-object with A LOT of elements
print(*some_superlong_list, sep ="\n")

# do something with some_super_long_list

print("IDs:", *map(id.some_superlong_list), sep = "\n")
print("new values:", *some_super_long_list, sep = "\n")
```

Of course, I could add a shortcut `sep = "\n"`, but I'd still have to assign the `sep` parameter for each `print` statement.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
print.sep = "\n" # something like this, to set the 'sep' parameter to "\n" by default
```

Comment: I also tried `print.__setattr__("sep","\n")`, which raised an AttributeError:  `'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sep'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625695/is-it-possible-to-change-a-functions-default-parameters-in-python):

```
from functools import partial

println = partial(print, sep='\n')
```

then you can use `println` whenever you want the line separation.