# Same function with 2 different names and pass an arg setting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to have a single function that can be run with two different names and pass a new arg setting as well as all others?

I am thinking something like this:

```
def func1(a, b=False):
    print(a)
    print(b)

func2 = func1(b=True)
```

Where this function is being run by other code on the command line and a is a string, lets say I set it to "hello".

Output for `func1`:

```
hello
False
```

Output for `func2`:

```
hello
True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625695/is-it-possible-to-change-a-functions-default-parameters-in-python

Comment: There is "functools.partial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define another function that calls the first function after setting the `b` argument to `True`.

```
def func2(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['b'] = True
    func1(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem I have with this way is the actual function in questions has many many args and I am aiming to bypass the need to pass so many args twice and rather by default pass all of them but change one.

Comment: I've updated it to show how to pass all the other arguments.